# javascript - How to get values from a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table that is dynamically created on the webpage. The table has 3 columns.'filename', 'fileurl', and a column with a textnode that says'download'.
Some thing like this

```
filename     fileurl        download
file1     www.pathtofile1   download
file2     www.pathtofile2   download
file3     www.pathtofile3   download
```

The requirement here is, if the user clicks the 'download' in a particular row, i should get the corresponding values of 'filename' and 'fileurl' in that row.
How do i do that?

Comment: You need to write a code that meets with your requirement. Duh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough

```js
$("table tr .download").click(function(){
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var name = row.find(".name").html(),
      url = row.find(".url").html();
  console.log(name,url)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="name">file1</td>
  <td class="url">www.pathtofile1</td>
  <td class="download">Download</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="name">file2</td>
  <td class="url">www.pathtofile2</td>
  <td class="download">Download</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="name">file3</td>
  <td class="url">www.pathtofile3</td>
  <td class="download">Download</td>
</tr>
```